# Select Solr Indexes and update them by Query

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I simple want to select numerous indexes and update their int values by Query for example, to delete an index we use a query below.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=
<delete><query>id:298253</query></delete>&commit=true
```

like above, I want to select indexes which contain int value(chid:128) and    change their sectioncode to 2118.

the below is my current query first it selects chid and change their section code to 2118. but It didn't work.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/new_core/update?stream.body=<query>chid:128</query>
<set>
<field name="sectioncode" >2118</field>
</set>&commit=true
```

please give me your kind advises

Answer (score 0):

Atomic updates [1] should be a feature that sounds like what you need, but have a look at the description and see if that fits your needs.

[1] https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates

Comment: Thank you for your advice but unfortunately I'm using solr 3.x version. So It won't be useful for my solr

Comment: In that case I believe the answer to your question is no, sorry.